# Content of tabularx environment squeezed at left margin - nesting problem?

Tags: tabularx

Under circumstances that I do not understand the content of a tabularx environment gets squeezed to the left margin.  The following code example produces the problem on my system (using xelatex):

```
\documentclass{article} % -*- coding: utf-8-unix -*-
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\geometry{a4paper,margin=1cm}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\usrchord}[2]{
   \vspace{0ex}
   \begin{tabularx}{0.23\textwidth}{*{#1}{X}}
      \Huge \bf #2
   \end{tabularx}
}
\newcommand{\usrlyricsxx}[2]{   
   \vspace{0ex}
   \begin{tabularx}{0.2\textwidth}{X|X}
      #1 & #2 \\
   \end{tabularx}
}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{4}{|X}|}
% Comment randomly any of the following lines to see the difference
   \usrchord{1}{A}    & \usrchord{1}{D}    & \usrchord{1}{E}    & \usrchord{1}{A}    \\
   \usrlyricsxx{a}{b} & \usrlyricsxx{c}{d} & \usrlyricsxx{e}{f} & \usrlyricsxx{g}{h} \\
   \usrchord{1}{A}    & \usrchord{1}{D}    & \usrchord{1}{E}    & \usrchord{1}{E}    \\
   \usrlyricsxx{i}{j} & \usrlyricsxx{k}{l} & \usrlyricsxx{m}{n} & \usrlyricsxx{o}{p} \\
   \usrlyricsxx{q}{}  \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Which results in the following output:

[image: content squeezed to the left margin]

If, as described in the comment, one of the rows of the tabularx environment is commented (for example, the first one), the result looks more like what I expect:

[image]

The example above is only one MWE as a representative of several constellations when this happens.  However, I hope that what I am doing wrong in this example applies to all the constellations.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Purpose of `\usrchord` is not clear. Its use gives result independent from number #1. The same result can be obtained with `\newcommand{\usrchord}[1]{\textbf{\Huge #1}}`.

Comment: @Zarko: It shall also be usable like `\usrchord{2}{A&D}`.

Comment: @DirkHerrmann, than you should add this case on your MWE ... By the way,. nesting `tabularx in `tabularx` usually make problems. Now I will try to make an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}

\newcommand{\usrchord}[2]{
   \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\hsize+\tabcolsep\relax}{*{#1}{>{\bfseries\Huge}X}}
      #2
   \end{tabularx}
}
\newcommand{\usrlyricsxx}[2]{
   \begin{tabular}{p{\dimexpr0.5\hsize-1.5\tabcolsep\relax}|
                   p{\dimexpr0.5\hsize-1.5\tabcolsep\relax}}
      #1 & #2 \\
   \end{tabular}
}

\usepackage{showframe}% for show page layout in this MWE ...
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{4}{|X}|}
\usrchord{1}{A}    & \usrchord{1}{D}    & \usrchord{1}{E}    & \usrchord{1}{A}    \\
\usrlyricsxx{a}{b} & \usrlyricsxx{c}{d} & \usrlyricsxx{e}{f} & \usrlyricsxx{g}{h} \\
\usrchord{1}{A}    & \usrchord{1}{D}    & \usrchord{1}{E}    & \usrchord{1}{E}    \\
\usrlyricsxx{i}{j} & \usrlyricsxx{k}{l} & \usrlyricsxx{m}{n} & \usrlyricsxx{o}{p} \\
\usrchord{2}{A & B}&\usrchord{4}{C & D & E & F}  \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Changes:

- new definitions of `\usrchord` and `\usrlyricsxx`
- `\usrchord` use standard `tabular` environment with `p{...}` columns type
- showed use `\usrchord` with more sub-cells

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the output for the MWE becomes garbled is the number of `X` columns: If this number gets too big the inner workings of the `tabularx` environment lead to a tex internal overflow (see [How to typeset tabularx with 34 columns? (Error message)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29194/how-to-typeset-tabularx-with-34-columns-error-message)).  And, the number of `X` columns considered for an outer `tabularx` environment includes all the `X` columns of all nested `tabularx` environments.

This can easily be verified by adding `\tracingtabularx` to the preamble of the MWE from the question: Running `xelatex` then produces the following debug output about the outermost `tabularx` environment:

```
(tabularx)     Table Width    Column Width    X Columns
(tabularx)      2212.40952pt    540.60239pt      31
(tabularx) Don't exceed \maxdimen
```

The number of 31 columns is one more than the 4 `X` columns of the outermost `tabularx` environment, plus the 8 `X` columns due to the uses of the `\usrchord` command, plus the 2*9 `X` columns due to the uses of the `\usrlyricsxx` command.

Coincidentially, the number 31 from the MWE is the exact boundary at which the overflow occurs: The number of columns (minus one) is multiplied with the initial column width, that is 31 * 540.60239pt = 16758.67409pt, which exceeds the tex limit of 16384pt minus epsilon.  Just removing one single of the `X` columns (e. g. by taking out one of the `\usrchord` commands) will avoid the overflow, as 30 * 540.60239pt = 16218.0717pt < 16384pt.  Therefore, also the commenting of any of the lines of the outer `tabularx` environment (as was described in the question) lead to a sufficiently small number of columns such that things worked as expected.

The problem of the overflow can only be solved by ensuring for each `tabularx` environment that the aggregated number of `X` columns does not become too big.  To achieve this it may be necessary to switch from `tabularx` to a different environment.  For the example from the question this would be recommendable for both the `\usrchord` and the `\usrlyricsxx` commands: If only one of them gets replaced, the problem will re-occur if more lines get added and thus again the column limit will be exceeded.

Comment: How you found that your MWE has 31 columns? I see only 4 which each has nested two columns tables.  This gives  8 columns. Width of nested tables should be determined in main table, right? But it seems that this is not a case (As far I see there is enough space for all columns in your table). If you somehow fix main columns width (as I did with `\usrlyricsxx` in my answer), then your problem disappear. I didn't tested possibilities (and now I haven't time for this) to use use `p{...}` columns instead of `X` and then use your original definition for `\usrchord` and `\usrlyricsxx`.

Comment: @Zarko: Each `\usrchord` introduces a table of its own with one column, and each `\usrlyricsxx` introduces a table of its own with two columns.  The fact that they all finally give an optical impression of only 8 columns is something that the `tabularx` algorithm does not even try to predict when processing the outermost table.  As I said, it is easy to verify using `\tracingtabularx`, which is also what brought me closer to understanding the reason for the strange behaviour I had encountered.